# Pycharm cannot update from Pycharm 2018.1 to 2020.1 due to an error 403

Tags: python, pycharm

When I go to settings , updates, check now, there is version 2020.1 so when I try to update it after a few minutes this ERROR message appears:

**Connection Error: Failed to prepare an update: // Cannot download 'https://download.jetbrains.com/python/PE-191.7479.40-191.7479.68-patch-win.jar': Request failed with status code 403 // Open download page. (today 01:33)**

I've already searched in the JetBrains forums but couldn't find anybody with the same issue

I'm using the free version (Community) of Pycharm from: jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

Comment: Are you using a legal version or a cracked one? Error 403 is an Access Denied error, probably because you don't have the credentials (like a product license) registered so they won't let you download the update. Let us know

Comment: I'm using the free version (Community)  of Pycharm from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows